# CakePHP Issue - site errors up

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web-server, cakephp

I  have a cakePHP site and I moved the site over to a new server today and for some reason I keep getting errors. It works fine on another server but this new one that has cpanel does not seem to be working right. Not sure what the issue is.

Some of the errors:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 549]

Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 554]


Warning (512): SQL Error: 1146: Table 'mycats.space' doesn't exist [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 440]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mycats/public_html/cake/basics.php:338) [APP/controllers/app_controller.php, line 168]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mycats/public_html/cake/basics.php:338) [APP/controllers/app_controller.php, line 169]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mycats/public_html/cake/basics.php:338) [APP/controllers/app_controller.php, line 170]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mycats/public_html/cake/basics.php:338) [APP/controllers/app_controller.php, line 175]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be to focus on the SQL error. I would confirm that the database was successfully imported. One of the database tables cannot be found, based off of the message:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1146: Table 'mycats.space' doesn't exist [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 440]
```

Once you've confirmed that the mycats.space exists, you'll be reducing the errors. The Notices and Warnings shouldn't prevent the site from loading, but they still should be addressed.

Bottom line, locate and fix the SQL error and then report back with the next set of errors & work through them.

-Brendan

Comment: Yep the issue was missing databases. Uploaded them but client did not have the site pointing to our servers during the time of messing around /facepalm

Comment: That worked out for the better then because the site would have experienced downtime due to the SQL error. I'm glad you got it sorted.